# clicar em campo de uma tabela carregar o formulario de editar com o id selecionado

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho uma tabela de usuários e gostaria que ao clicar no botão editar carregasse o formulário de editar sem dar refresh na página com o id selecionado usando jquery seria possível? abaixo segue o código:

```
<table class="table">
   <thead class="thead bg-info text-light">
     <tr>                    
       <th scope="col">ID</th>
       <th scope="col">Nome</th>
       <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
       <th scope="col">Nível</th>                  
       <th scope="col">Editar</th>
       <th scope="col">Excluir</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

     <?php

      include "../config/cnn.php";

      $query = $pdo->query("Select * FROM USUARIOS;");

      while ($linha = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))                           
         {                            
           echo'<tr>';                                             
            echo'<td>'."{$linha['id']}".'</td>';
            echo'<td>'."{$linha['administrador_nome']}".'</td>';                            
            echo'<td>'."$linha['administrador_email']}".'</td>';  
            echo'<td>'."$linha['administrador_nivel']}".'</td>';   
            echo'<td><a id="edituser"href="'."../frmEditar/frmEditUser.php?id="."{$linha['id']}".'">
           <span><i class="far fa-edit"></i></span></a></td>';
            echo'<td><a>
            <span><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span></a></td>';
          echo'</tr>';
                    }?>                
     </tbody>
   </table>            


Abaixo segue o script jquery que estou usando no sistema

    <script>
      $("#edituser").click(function(){
          $("#main").load("../frmEditar/frmEditUser.php");
      });      
    </script>
```

Comment: Tem certeza que deseja carregar uma página dentro de outra? Não seria melhor capturar o `id` e levar para uma página de edição?

Comment: Sim mas teria como fazer isso sem dar refresh na página?

Comment: Da sim. Busque por AJAX

Answer (score -1):

Tenta dessa forma. Você pode usar CSS para tornar o button transparente

```
<td><button type='button' onclick='pegaId(this)' value='{$linha['id']}'>Bla bla bla</button></td>

          <script>
             function pegaId(id){
             var id = id.value;
                }
          </script>
```

Comment: obrigado! muito obrigado
o código que deu foi o seguinte:

<button id="edituser" onclick="pegaId('. "{$linha['id']}" .')"></button>

<script >
      function pegaId(id) {    
         $("#main").load("../frmEditar/frmEditUser.php?id=" + id);      
      }           
    </script>